# How do I stop a component rendering before data is fetched?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Currently in react I have to functions in the componentDidMount lifecycle method in which call action creators to which fetch data. The component uses the data however, depending on how quick the response is determines if the data is there or not. How can i make it so the component doesn't render before data is inside it?

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getTotalHours()
    this.props.getTrained()
  }
```

Render Function:

```
render() {
    let hours = parseInt(_.map(this.props.hours, 'hours'));
    let trained = _.map(this.props.trained, 'trained');
    return (
      <div className="o-layout--center u-margin-top-large">
          <div className="o-layout__item u-width-1/2@medium u-width-1/4@large">
            <div style={{width: '80%', margin: '0 auto'}}>
              <PieChart data={hours} goal={100} label=' Training Hours Completed'/>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Action Creator stores returned values from request in the application state:

```
 export function getTotalHours() {
   const url = `${ROOT_URL}dashboard/hours`
   const request = axios.get(url)
   return {
     type: FETCH_HOURS,
     payload: request
   }
 }
```

Comment: you can either just return an empty div which will render nothing till data isn't fetched, or you can add default values and render something with initial data, say hours = 0, and when you get data, you can update the state which will update your view.

Comment: move this.props.getTotalHours() and this.props.getTrained() to componentWillMount and check the application state before mapping it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Control your async actions using `then` or `await` and use `this.state` to control whether or not your content gets loaded. Only render your content after `this.state.loaded === true`

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    loaded: false
  }
}

async componentDidMount() {
    await this.props.getTotalHours()
    await this.props.getTrained()
    this.setState({loaded: true})
  }

content() {
  let hours = parseInt(_.map(this.props.hours, 'hours'));
  let trained = _.map(this.props.trained, 'trained');
  return (
    <div className="o-layout--center u-margin-top-large">
    <div className="o-layout__item u-width-1/2@medium u-width-1/4@large">
      <div style={{width: '80%', margin: '0 auto'}}>
        <PieChart data={hours} goal={100} label=' Training Hours Completed'/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

render() {
  return (
  <div>
    {this.state.loaded ? this.content() : null}
  </div>
  )
}
```

edit: If you care about performance in your API calls, you can run them in parallel with `Promise.all`.

```
async componentDidMount() {
   const hours = this.props.getTotalHours()
   const trained = this.props.getTrained()
   await Promise.all([hours, trained])
   this.setState({loaded: true})
 }
```

Comment: I have tried this and it will return 1 of the 2 pieces of data being fetched, the other is still rendering an undefined value, even though the value has been fetched.

Comment: @MattEllis Are you sure the data structures you're trying to map over looks the way you're expecting?

Comment: when logging what is returned the hours is always returned as NaN before the second render when it becomes an integer

Comment: @MattEllis You can set a boolean to control that as well. Wherever it is relevant, you can use [Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) as your conditional.

Answer (score 3):

In your constructor, declare a state variable to track if data is loaded. For example:

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    dataLoaded: false
  }
}
```

Then in your `render` method, return null if `this.state.dataLoaded` is false:

```
render () {
  const { dataLoaded } = this.state
  return (
    <div>
      {
        dataLoaded &&
        <YourComponent />
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

And in the methods you use to fetch data, make sure you call `this.setState({ dataLoaded: true })` when data has been fetched

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop the render but you can give conditions to what to render.

**Example**

```
render() {
    if(this.props.hours. length <= 0 || this.props.trained.length <= 0 ) {
      return (<div><span>Loading...</span></div>);
    } else {
      let hours = parseInt(_.map(this.props.hours, 'hours'));
      let trained = _.map(this.props.trained, 'trained');
      return (
        <div className="o-layout--center u-margin-top-large">
            <div className="o-layout__item u-width-1/2@medium u-width-1/4@large">
              <div style={{width: '80%', margin: '0 auto'}}>
                <PieChart data={hours} goal={100} label=' Training Hours Completed'/>
              </div>
            </div>
      )
    }
```

Comment: Downside here is that when there are no `hours`or `trained` entries, your app will keep showing "Loading..." as if it was hanging.