# React: "TypeError: props.category is undefined" when accessing key of category

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm receiving JSON object from backend which contains a name `category` which value is an object. This object contains names `_id` and `name`. But when I access the `_id` using `props.category._id` it's giving me this error:

`TypeError: props.category is undefined`

Actually, the JSON object is the document of MongoDB and `category` is the field that contains the reference to another document.

The backend is written in Node.js and I'm using Mongoose.

I can share the backend as well as the frontend code of the required section.

**App.js**

```
<Route path="/blog/:id" exact><SinglePost /></Route>
```

**singlepost.js : React Component for the page (SinglePost)**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import axios from 'axios';
import Comments from '../parts/comments';
import RelatedPosts from '../parts/relatedpost';
import BlogContent from '../parts/blogcontent';

class SinglePost extends Component 
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      blog: [],
      commentCount: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/blogs/get/' + this.props.match.params.id)
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        blog: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/comments/count/' + this.props.match.params.id)
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        commentCount: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  render()
  {
    return (
      <div>


      <section className="blog-section">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="single-post no-sidebar">
            <div className="title-single-post">
              <a className="text-link" href="#"></a>
              <h1>{this.state.blog.title}</h1>
              <ul className="post-tags">
                <li>{new Date(this.state.blog.createdAt).toDateString()}</li>
                <li><a href="#">{this.state.commentCount.count} comments</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="single-post-content">
              <img src={"../../" + this.state.blog.imageUrl} alt="" />
              <div className="post-content">
                <div className="post-social">
                  <span>Share</span>
                  <ul className="share-post">
                    <li><a href="#" className="facebook"><i className="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" className="twitter"><i className="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" className="pinterest"><i className="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <BlogContent blog = {this.state.blog} />
              </div>
              <RelatedPosts category = {this.state.blog.category} />
              
            </div>

            <Comments />

          </div>
            </div>
        </section>

    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(SinglePost);
```

**relatedposts.js : React Component for related post(RelatedPosts)**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

let RelatedPost = props => (
    <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
        <div className="news-post standard-post text-left">
            <div className="image-holder">
                <a href="single-post.html"><img src={"../../" + props.currentPost.imageUrl}  alt="" /></a>
            </div>
            <a className="text-link" href="#">{props.currentPost.category.name}</a>
            <h2><a href="single-post.html">{props.currentPost.title}</a></h2>
            <ul className="post-tags">
                <li>{new Date(this.state.blog.createdAt).toDateString()}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
);

const RelatedPosts = (props) => {
    var relatedPosts = [];
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/get/related-posts/' + props.category._id)
    .then(res => {
        relatedPosts = res.data;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

    return (
        <div className="related-box">
            <h2>Related Posts</h2>
            <div className="row">
                {relatedPosts.map((currentPost, index) => {
                    return <RelatedPost currentPost = {currentPost} key = {index} />
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default RelatedPosts;
```

**JSON from backend**

```
{"featured":false,"likes":5,"_id":"5f084b96acb1d60bcee3f0fa","title":"Lorem Ipsum","description":"Lorem Ipsum Blog","imageUrl":"upload/blog/f1.jpg","category":{"_id":"5f05ae4b27ef066f94673265","name":"Technology"},"createdAt":"2020-07-10T11:05:58.044Z","updatedAt":"2020-07-10T11:05:58.044Z","__v":0}
```

Comment: can you post your react code

Comment: I added the code to my question. You can check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change you `SinglePost` component like this where you'll check if data has arrived and set in your states.
One way you can do it as follows

SinglePost.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import axios from 'axios';
import Comments from '../parts/comments';
import RelatedPosts from '../parts/relatedpost';
import BlogContent from '../parts/blogcontent';

class SinglePost extends Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      blog: [],
      commentCount: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/blogs/get/' + this.props.match.params.id)
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        blog: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/comments/count/' + this.props.match.params.id)
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        commentCount: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  render()
  {
    return (
      <div>
        <section className="blog-section">
          <div className="container">
            {this.state.blog.length > 0 ? // <----- here
              <div className="single-post no-sidebar">
                <div className="title-single-post">
                <a className="text-link" href="#"></a>
                <h1>{this.state.blog.title}</h1>
                <ul className="post-tags">
                  <li>{new Date(this.state.blog.createdAt).toDateString()}</li>
                  <li><a href="#">{this.state.commentCount.count} comments</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="single-post-content">
                <img src={"../../" + this.state.blog.imageUrl} alt="" />
                <div className="post-content">
                  <div className="post-social">
                  <span>Share</span>
                  <ul className="share-post">
                      <li><a href="#" className="facebook"><i className="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" className="twitter"><i className="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" className="pinterest"><i className="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
                  </ul>
                  </div>
                  <BlogContent blog = {this.state.blog} />
                </div>
                <RelatedPosts category = {this.state.blog.category} />
                
                </div>
                <Comments />
              </div>
              : <h1>Loading</h1> // <----- here
          </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(SinglePost);
```

Comment: I got what you are trying to say. But I'm still confused about how to achieve it. Please explain a little bit more. That would be more helpful.

Comment: It will be more helpful if you tell me the function/method which I will need to do that.

Comment: the issue here was that on page load your page was getting rendered and internal components were getting called but the data was not returned from the API and set in the states which was required for internal components, so what I did, inside `render` function I asked it to check whether data is present inside state or not, if present go ahead and render the page or else show loading message....There are multiple ways you can do it...I showed one of the way... [few more ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46825735/how-do-i-stop-a-component-rendering-before-data-is-fetched/46825893)